# Output of lsblk includes both pipes and back ticks

Tags: output, lsblk

```bsh
sda                                                                                
|-sda1 ntfs     Recovery       F49E60439E5FFD0C                                    
|-sda2 vfat                    0E62-991B                              61.6M    36% /boot/efi
|-sda3                                                                             
|-sda4 ntfs                    5EEC0B13EC0AE55D                                    
|-sda5 ext4     Home           f142204b-a3c1-4ed4-b255-944659cef7bd  239.8G    59% /home
|-sda6 swap                    97399d72-dc57-4f90-a8c7-e9409582ccd9                [SWAP]
|-sda7 ext4     Backup         da05c9bb-d9f3-44dd-872d-ee106d971561   67.4G    44% /mnt/Backup
|-sda8 ext4                    093e80bf-e5f4-4b61-9f6c-26981b9710ab   29.9G    49% /
`-sda9 ext4     SwapPossible   115a401a-2c85-4b54-9d04-9a7051193249                
sdb                                                                                
|-sdb1 ntfs     PortableData   4E1AEA7B1AEA6007                       12.8G    98% /media/nikh/PortableData
`-sdb2 ext4     PortableBackup bcc13a36-eae7-4c36-a9b1-98e641d41fb4  256.8G    14% /media/nikh/PortableBackup1
```

My question is: Why sda9 and sdb2 starts with a backquote, while others starts with a pipe character? Does it have some special meaning?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Backquote in lsblk output](https://superuser.com/q/1458585/432690). The answer there is more elaborate than the one you got here (so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a layout-thing.

It makes it easier for the user to see that `sda9` and `sdb2` are the last ones in their respective lists.

Nothing to worry about.